# How to get parent's class attributes into the scope of the derived class?

Tags: python

I have a class which defines multiple class attributes and multiple methods. These methods have default arguments equal to class attributes. Sometimes attributes are used from methods (with `self.` prepended).

```
class MyClass:
    VAL1 = "hello"
    VAL2 = "world"

    def foo(self, x=VAL1, y=VAL2):
        if x == self.VAL1:
            print "yay"

    def bar(self, t=VAL2):
        pass
```

Now, for some reason, I want to move the attributes declaration into a separate class and split the methods among its children.

```
class Base:
    VAL1 = "hello"
    VAL2 = "world"

class Derived1(Base):
    def foo(self, x=VAL1, y=VAL2):
        if x == self.VAL1:
            print "yay"

class Derived2(Base):
    def bar(self, t=VAL2):
        pass
```

However, that does not work because Base's arguments, VAL1 and VAL2, are out of scope in derived classes.

Now the important point: **I cannot change the code of the methods***. So the obvious way of writing `def bar(self, t=Base.VAL2)` does not work.

Is there any other way of extending the scope?

I'm using Python 2.7.

(*) There are literally dozens of methods in the class, and I don't want to change the existing code too much because similar coding convention is used elsewhere in the project. If you want to argue, please think about this question as of an educational one.

Comment: Using class attributes (i.e. static attributes) as default arguments to instance methods is... rather strange.

Comment: It is strange because the class attribute is mutable but the default argument doesn't obey this.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga These class attributes are constant by semantics. Say, DEFAULT_CONNECTION_IP.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov yes, I would still just put them at the module level. That would be more typical, and would happen to solve your problem. Or if you want to be able to override in derived classes, use the `kwarg=None` then `if kwarg is None: kwarg = self.VAL1` idiom in the method body

Comment: The original design was a bad design, and now you are finding out why. Don't make it worse. Time to refactor!

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
class Base:
    VAL1 = "hello"

class Derived1(Base):
    VAL1 = Base.VAL1

    def foo(self, x=VAL1):
        print(x)

d = Derived1()
d.foo()
```

**edit:** I'm not sure it looks pretty, but it's more automated and perhaps suits you better.

```
import inspect

class Base:
    VAL1 = "hello"
    VAL2 = "world"

class Derived1(Base):
    for var, val in inspect.getmembers(Base):
        locals()[var] = val

    def foo(self, x=VAL1, y=VAL2):
        if x == self.VAL1:
            print "yay"
        if y == self.VAL2:
            print "hoorah!"

d1 = Derived1()
d1.foo()
```

**double edit:**

If you don't want to copy `__doc__` and `__module__`, you could use

```
for var, val in inspect.getmembers(Base):
    if(var[:2] != '__'):
        locals()[var] = val
```

As far as I know, this is not a very common thing to do in Python, so I'm guessing that most solutions will be a bit ugly (but I'd be curious to see a counterexample!)

Comment: It is not much better than defining arguments directly in children, eliminating the base.

Comment: That's going to end up copying a bunch of stuff it shouldn't copy. At least `__doc__` and `__module__`, and likely more.

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll try and check if it works in my case. Though a bit obscure, I'd say.

Comment: Even with the hacky `'__'` check, you're still going to copy a bunch of stuff you shouldn't. For example, you're very likely to stomp over method overrides, and if you ever want to use `abc` or descend from classes that use `abc`, you're going to copy a bunch of abc-internal attributes too. Editing `locals()` is also a horrible, fragile thing that the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) specifically warns you not to do; it happens to not bite you in the specific context you're doing it in, in current CPython implementations, but it's not guaranteed.